# CheckBox CheckedChanged event added from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes that I add from my code behind, but I can't get the CheckedChanged event to fire.

This code is being called on page load:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.AutoPostBack = true;
cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;

cb.ToolTip = dr["Id"].ToString();
cb.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = dr["Id"].ToString();
lbl.AssociatedControlID = cb.ID;

dvCheckboxes.Controls.Add(cb);
dvCheckboxes.Controls.Add(lbl);
dvCheckboxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

And the event:

```
void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(((CheckBox)sender).ToolTip);
}
```

I've put a breakpoint in the CheckedChanged event, but it's never reached.

**What I've tried:**

- putting the code in `if(!IsPostBack)`, but no difference.
- `cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged);`
- `cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.cb_CheckedChanged);`
- `cb.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled;`
- tried putting the code in `Page_Init` instead of `Page_Load`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@johan, Try this. Create the checkboxes in PageInit instead of Pageload. Also provide an appropriate id for the Checkbox.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.AutoPostBack = true;
            cb.CheckedChanged +=cb_CheckedChanged;
            cb.CausesValidation = false;
            cb.ToolTip = "Hello";
            cb.ID = "chk_test";

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "test";
            lbl.AssociatedControlID = cb.ID;

            dvCheckboxes.Controls.Add(cb);
            dvCheckboxes.Controls.Add(lbl);
            dvCheckboxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }
        protected void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(((CheckBox)sender).ToolTip);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't need to put it in Page_init, just needed a proper id =)

Answer (score 0):

Add event in your site code - not code behind:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" Runat="server" CheckedChanged="cb_CheckedChanged" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't since the checkboxes are added from code behind. My asp is just `<div id="dvCheckboxes" runat="server"></div>`